# Going from $\tan y = \cdots$ to $y=\tan^{-1}(\cdots)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have a question about my teacher's solution to this problem:

> If $\tan y = \dfrac{x}{b}$ and $\tan z = \dfrac{10+x}{b}$, solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ and $z$.

[original question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i35pM.png)

My Pre-Calculus teacher gave us the above problem, and gave the solution as:

$$y = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x\tan z}{10+x}\right) \tag{1}$$

However, I am skeptical. The first few steps of solving this problem were very easy, and I got to where:

$$\tan y = \frac{x\tan z}{10+x} \tag{2}$$

However, it seems to me that you *cannot* simply jump from there to the answer my teacher gave -- that is, that given the statement in the previous line it *need not* *be true* (although it *could* be true) that $y$ equals what it equals in the teacher's answer above.

This is because of the restricted range of the arctangent/inverse tangent function: $-\frac{\pi}{2}<y<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Therefore, aren't there an infinite number of answers to the question? (I'm not entirely sure that my "need not be true" statement above is actually the logically correct way of framing my concern, but hopefully you all get a sense of what I'm getting at.)

Comment: Please take the time to learn [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting mathematical expressions here. With images disabled, your question is incomprehensible. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers.

Comment: You need to assume $x \not= -10$.

Comment: You are correct; the value of $y$ is only determined up to multiples of $\pi$. That is, if $y=a$ is any solution for $y$, then so is $y=a\pm n\pi$ for any nonnegative integer $n$. If you do not have any a priori restrictions to the possible values of $y$, then the answer given is incomplete. For instance, if $b=1$, $x=0$, then you have $\tan(z)=10$ and $\tan(y) = 0$. The possible values for $y$ are $y=n\pi$, with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, but your professor’s answers only gives you $y=\arctan(0) = 0$.